What is the use of RequestCache in SpringBoot Security?
I was going through Spring Boot Security guide(link) and I came across RequestCaching. As far I can understand, it can be used when an unauthenticated user clicks a secured link, and is redirected to login/signup page, and if the credentials provided are correct, spring filters forward this request(request with login credentials) to secured link with access ?
Am I correct or is there something more to RequestCache? More uses cases would be highly appreciated.
